# Register Synchronization

Tags: embedded, microcontroller

What is meant by register synchronization in micro-controllers?

ATMEL SAM D20 boards use an ARM Cortex M0, in there framework they use two methods of setting/clearing output pins on the board. First one is **OUTSET.reg** which uses shift operation to build up a mask, then that mask is used with a logical operator to set or clear a specific bit. The second one is **OUTSET.bit.OUTSET** which according to the header files is used to set a specific bit (specific pin). I tried searching for the difference between the two and all I could find was a forum response

> Because for registers that need synchronization manipulating individual bits is risky and you can't do multiple bits in a row without synchronizing each and every of them. And that's just silly.

Here is a snippet from ATMEL port.h header file

```
typedef union {
  struct {
    uint32_t OUTSET:32;   //bit:  0..31  Port Data Output Value Set         
  } bit;                  //Structure used for bit  access                  
  uint32_t reg;           //Type      used for register access              
} PORT_OUTSET_Type;
```

Comment: You may want to search for and read about "bit banding".  The synchronization issue may just be an aside.

Comment: @kkrambo: That is not the bit-band region (that does not work with a `struct`, but uses different address ranges), but a speciality of the Atmel devices! Does the M0 even support bit-banding? IIRC, this is M3/4 only. Anyway, it is a bus-interface feature.

Comment: Objects don't "use operations". They just exist. It is a matter of the code. In general when programming at hardware-level one **always** should first read the reference-manual, datasheet, etc. and have them at hand during programming. IOW: RTFineManual! Don't just follow some forums who spread half-understood facts

Comment: The SAM D20 [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-42129-SAM-D20_Datasheet.pdf) only talks about OUTSET itself.

Comment: @Olaf: The only explanation that I can come up with after reading the datasheet and other sources is that if I want to change the state of a particular pin without affecting any other pins then if I use OUTSET.reg, I would be reading the current state of the register ORing it with a mask and writing it back (read-modify-write), but if I use OUTSET.bit then I won't have to worry about other pins, I can individually modify pin state without read-modify-write operation.

Comment: This is what the datasheet says about register synchronization

_**All peripherals are composed of one digital bus interface connected to the APB or AHB bus and running from a corresponding clock in the Main Clock domain, and one peripheral core running from the peripheral Generic Clock (GCLK). Communication between these clock domains must be synchronized.**_

Does this mean that there are 2 copies of the same register one connected to the bus and the other to peripheral core, and writing to the one in the bus is synchronized with the one in the peripheral core?

Comment: Well, I don't know this device and its particular registers. But a short peek at the datasheet gave me some hint already. I can't spend more time on that, but you should read the PORT section **carefully**. Hint: The ports are connected to IOBUS, not (just) APB.

Answer (score -1):

I am not an Atmel user, but I know the answer for Microchip, and their CPU  may be the same.

If you set (or clear) multiple bits in a register, the sequence is

1) Read the register
2) Or the value read with the mask of the bits you want to set
3) Write the new value back to the register

The problem with this is if an interrupt occurs at step 2, and if the interrupt takes priority, and sets bits in the same register, then the register will end up with the wrong bits set.  The solution would be to disable interrupt while the register bits are being changed.

Some CPU's provide an alternate method, a bit set feature built into the hardware, so you can set a bit with a single instruction without worrying about the process being interrupted.  The disadvantage is you can set only one single bit, so setting multiple bits requires an instruction for each bit.